# Overhauled (rebuilt) engine vs factory-assembled engine

Tags: rebuild

Most engines on average need a complete overhaul after about 250k miles. Many people do it and claim to use their cars for a couple of decades later. However, it is usually said that overhauled engines will never last as long as a brand new engine which is assembled in factory (even if they are assembled by the factory's technicians themselves!). Why? If during overhaul, you replace anything that needs to be replaced and repair anything that needs to be repaired, why shouldn't your engine last as long as a new engine? Do overhauled engines have a short life span even if they are assembled exactly based on what is recommended by the factory in the repair manual along with OEM parts?

Comment: Are you working within specs or blueprinting?

Comment: I'm currently not working on any project. I was just curious to know if overhauling an engine is worth it or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A properly overhauled engine will last as long as a new one, if you look at aviation piston engines as an example, fully overhauled engines have the same hour expectations as a brand new one. As a new engine is much more expensive than an overhaul most opt for the second option as it gets you the same result for less money.

With car engines an engine rebuild is often an opportunity to fix known problems or make improvements, for example enabling an engine to run on unleaded fuel or increasing performance. Sometimes a rebuild will give you something better than what rolled out of the factory.

However, not all engines can be economically overhauled, if the block is out of tolerance, has cracks or has become warped there may be no way to fix it.